# How not to unmount previously opened screen of Drawer Navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, native-base

I am using react-native-navigation and trying to create a DrawerNavigator which does not unmount the previously opened screens just like how TabNavigator works. Because one of my screens contains a webview and I do not want it to reload everytime I change screens.

Here is some sample code in App.js..

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    PageWithWebview: { screen: PageWithWebview},
    Settings: { screen: Settings },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",   
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar user={global.user} />
  }
);

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Drawer",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);

export default () =>
  <Root>
    <AppNavigator/>
  </Root>;
```

And in my Sidebar component I have buttons to navigate to a different route depending on what is selected .

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(selected, { userDetails: global.user })}
```

Comment: This behavior seems to have changed with later versions of react navigation.  You may find that by updating your package to a newer version they no longer unmount previous screens.   https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2277

Comment: FYI , the new behavior can be overridden to get back to the old behavior that unmounts inactive screens.  https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/11/17/react-navigation-3.0.html#drawer-now-keeps-inactive-tabs-in-memory-by-default

Comment: what I did back then was to place other screens in modals. I will try this soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the later versions of react native navigation they added the **unmountInactiveScreens** property for the DrawerNavigator

**unmountInactiveScreens**
Whether a screen should be unmounted when navigating away from it. Unmounting a screen resets any local state in the screen as well as state of nested navigators in the screen. Defaults to false.